# disable past dates on datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

How to disable past dates from the current date on a datetimepicker? I tried few posts for similar question but was unable to achieve it, Below is what I tried

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
 href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
});
</script>

<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
<input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy" type="text"/>
<span class="add-on">
  <i  data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
  </i>
</span>
```

I also tried

```
$("datetimepicker2").datepicker({ changeYear: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showOn: 'none', showButtonPanel: true,  minDate:'0d' });
```

and

```
$("#datetimepicker2").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

Comment: So far with help from http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: May be this post helpful:[Disable previous dates in date picker](https://devnote.in/how-to-disable-previous-dates-in-date-picker-using-jquery)

Answer (score 65):

Give zero to `mindate` and it'll disabale past dates.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

here is a <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/ZL2Bc/)**</kbd> working example http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/ZL2Bc/

[The official documentation is available here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: This works fine in jsfiddle but not in my project, I also included  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
still not working

Comment: Yes this works fine in JSFiddler but its when we add jQuery UI and I am not suppose to use jQuery UI in my project as I am using boostrap, is there another way to do so without jQuery UI?

Comment: "+1" with use this tutorial helpful: [How to disable previous dates in date picker using JQuery](https://devnote.in/how-to-disable-previous-dates-in-date-picker-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 20):

Problem fixed :)

below is the working code

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: '-0m'
        //endDate: '+2d'
    }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
        $('#sDate1').text($('#datepicker').data('date'));
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');
    });

})
```

Comment: whose ID is the #sDate1?

Answer (score 15):

`minDate: dateToday` Or `minDate: '0'` is the key here. Try to set the minDate property.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: dateToday // minDate: '0' would work too
    });
});
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847287/changing-mindate-option-in-jquery-datepicker-not-working)

Comment: hope the jQuery UI js is included

Comment: I am not suppose to use jQuery UI in my project as I am using boostrap, is there another way to do so without jQuery UI?

Comment: http://network.convergenceservices.in/forum/40-joomla-tricks/2287-making-joomla-default-calendar-work-like-jquery-date-picker.html

Comment: Done, below is the code:

$(function(){
        
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            startDate: '-0m'
            //endDate: '+2d'
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $('#sDate1').text($('#datepicker1').data('date'));
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker('hide');
        });
              
    });

Answer (score 10):

try this,

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date()});
```

Here, new Date() implies today's date....

Answer (score 9):

```
$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

**This will work:**

```
 var dateToday = new Date();    
 $(function () {
     $("#date").datepicker({ 
         minDate: dateToday 
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 7):

Below solution worked for me. I hope, this will help you also.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ startDate:'+0d' });
});
```

Comment: `startDate: '+0d'` only worked. `new Date()` solution didnt work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$("#datetimepicker2").datepicker({ startDate: "+0d" });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set date on page load then use this:

```
 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  minDate: new Date()
  });
```

This will set today's date as start date on page load itself and disable all the previous dates.
But if you want to set date on click of particular text-box instead of setting it on page load then use this:
    `$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("click", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());
    });`

In place of new Date(), we can use any string specifying Date in a format specified by us if we don't want to set current date as minimum date.
e.g:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate("10/15/2018");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var dateToday = new Date();

$('#datepicker').datepicker({                                     
    'startDate': dateToday
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 3):

this works for me,

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    startDate: new Date()
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable all previous dates, give start date as today date

```
startDate: new Date()
```

**Solution: disable all previous dates from today**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ startDate: new Date()});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div> Select Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></div>
```

**Solution: disable all past dates from a particular date.**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ startDate: new Date("2019-10-15")});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div> Select Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></div>
```

This will disable all days before the date **15th October 2019 (2019-10-15)**

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-start-date="0d">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_id" name="input_name" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score 1):

you have just introduce parameter startDate as mentioned below.

```
var todaydate = new Date();
    $(".leave-day").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        todayHighlight: true,
        startDate: todaydate     
      }
    ).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        var dateCalendar = e.format();
        dateCalendar = moment(dateCalendar, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $("#date-leave").val(dateCalendar);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Old date can excluded from `datetimepicker` by
give all your datepicker inputs or textboxes attribute `data-name='date'` then

```
$('*[data-name="date"]').datetimepicker({
          format: 'L',
          minDate: new Date()
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this'
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- table -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end table -->

    <script>
       $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy",
            maxDate: 0,

            onSelect: function () {



                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
        });
        $('#to_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy"
        });

       });
       </script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- table -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end table -->

    <script>
       $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy",
            maxDate: 0,

            onSelect: function () {



                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
        });
        $('#to_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy"
        });

       });
       </script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- table -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end table -->

    <script>
       $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy",
            maxDate: 0,

            onSelect: function () {



                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
        });
        $('#to_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy"
        });

       });
       </script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- table -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end table -->

    <script>
       $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy",
            maxDate: 0,

            onSelect: function () {



                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
        });
        $('#to_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy"
        });

       });
       </script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- table -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- end table -->

    <script>
       $(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $("#from_date").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy",
            maxDate: 0,

            onSelect: function () {



                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

                $('#to_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 0);
                $('#to_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            }
        });
        $('#to_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "mm/d/yy"
        });

       });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datetimepicker2").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", 
  minDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('#li_from_date').appendDtpicker({
    "dateOnly": true,
    "autodateOnStart": false,
    "dateFormat": "DD/MM/YYYY",
    "closeOnSelected": true,
    "futureonly": true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**this worked in my wordpress plugin
**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
           $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0});
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an end date based on start date using datepicker

```
  $("#AddEvent_txtStartDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            minDate = $("#AddEvent_txtStartDate").datepicker("getDate");
            var mDate = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()));
            $("#AddEvent_txtEndDate").datepicker("setDate", mDate);
            $("#AddEvent_txtEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", mDate);
        }
    });  
    $("#AddEvent_txtEndDate").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me,

$(function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        startDate: '-0m',
        autoclose: true
     });
});

Comment: The reason why this is working is because you're adding a minus (-) before the 0m. Which means minus - months from today. You can find some more info about this [here](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/ca11c450/README.md#options).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This scripts works when you're using the `daterangepicker` library.
If you want to disable the `Sat` or `Sunday` date on `daterangepicker` then put this line of code.

```
        $("#event_start").daterangepicker({
            // minDate: new Date(),
            minYear: 2000,
            showDropdowns: true,
            singleDatePicker: true,
            timePicker: true,
            timePicker24Hour: false,
            timePickerIncrement: 15,
            drops:"up",
            isInvalidDate: function(date) {
                //return true if date is sunday or saturday
                return (date.day() == 0 || date.day() == 6);
            },
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A'
            }
        });
```

OR if you want to disable the `previous date` also with `sat` and `sun` then uncomment the this line `minDate: new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

try this. It is working for me.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
   startDate: new Date()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add option of

```
startDate: new Date()
```

refer like this

```
$('.installment_date').datepicker({
     startDate: new Date()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DateTime.now()` in `firstDate: DateTime.now()`

Please see the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76pul.png).

```
DateTime? date;
  Future pickDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final initialDate = DateTime.now();
    final newDate = await showDatePicker(
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      context: context,
      initialDate: date ?? initialDate,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
    );

    if (newDate == null) return;

    setState(() => date = newDate);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Previous one day back.
//minDate 0 means current date, and MinDate -1 previous 1 day back.
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange: "-0:+1",
    minDate: -1
    
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This. its works for me:

```
 const startDatePicker = document.getElementById('travelStartDate');
 startDatePicker.addEventListener('focus', () => {
   startDatePicker.min = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
 });
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

[To disable past dates](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-set-min), Add this given js:

```
var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate();
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker');
picker.set('min',true);`][1]
```