# Boostrap datetimepicker: startDate: -Infinity not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, datepicker

I'm working with [bootstrap datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and I want to disabled the past days and I used

> startDate: -Infinity

to set a minimum date but it  doesn't work. And also i received an error in my console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

I also used the working code from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker) but still not working in my project.
Here is my code:

```
   <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
     <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text"></input>
        <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
        </i>
        </span>
   </div>
```

My Javascript:

```
  $(function(){ 
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ 
        startDate: -Infinity , 
        pickTime: false
    });
  });
```

Regards!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem Fixed: 
I just change my script to:

```
   $(function(){ 
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate());

  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({                            
        startDate: date,
        pickTime: false
  });

  });
```