# How to disable previous dates on the TO calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is the script I am using. What changes to be done?

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3,

$( "#to" ).datepicker
  defaultDate: "+1w",
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 3
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete and unclear. Please fix the code and elaborate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable past dates on datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
var today = new Date();
var yesterday = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1)
```

then add below property in your to `date picker function`

```
minDate : yesterday
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :-

Have to add this code in `$( "#from" ).datepicker`

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
  $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate
```

Have to add this code in `$( "#to" ).datepicker`

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
             $( "#toDateRange" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete to code for that

```
 var dateToday = new Date();
     $(".datefrom" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
         minDate: dateToday,

         onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".dateto" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      },
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
             var option = this.class == "datefrom" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
              instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
              date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
         }
     });

$(".dateto" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',

    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( ".datefrom" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
  });


$('.datefrom,.dateto').change(selector)
```

It will disable the previous date in from calender and according to the selection done in from calender the to calender will get updated automatically and disabled previous date..