# Disable past date code in jquery is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I link the jquery file in my page that can simply show datepicker but the function that have code of disabling past date is not working. When i code for displaying specific date is also not working. feedback will be high appreciated.

```
<script>
   $("#datepicker").datepicker();

   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: -0
        });
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: `minDate: 0` not -0, or `minDate: new Date()`

Comment: Possible duplicate or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker

Comment: minDate: 0  is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minDate: 0`

```
<script>    
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: 0
        });
    });       
</script>
```