# Disable all previous dates in datepicker according to the date selected

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In this case, 2 datepickers are there. Disable all previous dates in datepicker according to the date selected

```
  $('#first_date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd MM, yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: Data.startdate,
    endDate: '0d'
  })

  $('#second_date').datepicker({
    endDate: '0d'
  });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1029767/how-disable-previous-dates-from-jquery-date-picker