# How do I disable past dates in daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

For my laravel project I'm using a date range picker to choose my start date and end date what I want to do now is disable the past dates make it so it's not clickable any date before today cannot be clicked. How can I do that?

**html file**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
       <label class="control-label">Start Date -  End Date</label>
       <input type="text" onclick = "getTime()" class="form-control input-daterange-timepicker" id = 'daterange' name="daterange" value="" />
       <input type="hidden" id="start_time" name="start_time"/>
       <input type="hidden" id="end_time" name="end_time"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

**My Script**

```
<script>


        $(function() {
            $('.edit-modal').on('click', function() {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var event_name = $(this).data('event_name');
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                if(dd<10){ dd='0'+dd }
                if(mm<10){ mm='0'+mm }
                var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
                //var event_venue = $(this).data('event_venue');
                $('#edit_evid').val(id);
                $('#edit_event_name').val(event_name);
            });
        });
            // Daterange picker
            $('.input-daterange-datepicker').daterangepicker({
                buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
                applyClass: 'btn-info',
                cancelClass: 'btn-inverse'
            });
            $('.input-daterange-timepicker').daterangepicker({
                timePicker: true,
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm p',
                timePickerIncrement: 30,
                timePicker12Hour: true,
                timePickerSeconds: false,
                buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
                applyClass: 'btn-info',
                cancelClass: 'btn-inverse'
            });
            $('.input-limit-datepicker').daterangepicker({
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                minDate: today,
                maxDate: '06/30/2015',
                buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
                applyClass: 'btn-info',
                cancelClass: 'btn-inverse',
                dateLimit: {
                    days: 6
                }
            });
        </script>
```

the days before current date should be disabled

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable past dates on datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757918/disable-past-dates-on-datepicker)

Comment: What @ascsoftw means with duplicate is that your question allready has an answer in StackOverflow. Someone made a similar question and got an answer, and you can use that answer to solve your problem. He is not saying that you made that question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var dateToday = new Date();    
 $(function () {
     $("#start_time").datepicker({ 
         minDate: dateToday 
     });
 });
```