# Set start date where all dates before the specified is disabled (JQuery Datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the JQuery Datepicker in which I want to set a static start date, where any date before the specified is either disabled or blanked out. I have tried using the MinDate setting but nothing has worked. Maybe I am misunderstanding what MinDate actually does?

Edit, here's the code I am trying (setting the minDate to 2015-12-01):

```
<script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'DD, d MM yy',
        minDate: new Date(2015, 12 - 1, 01)
        }) 
      });
</script>
```

As sourced from this page: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847287/changing-mindate-option-in-jquery-datepicker-not-working)

Comment: Please edit your question adding your code to show what you tried. See how to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VincenzoC I added the code I am trying.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you shared, just check that you included all required resources (jQuery and jQuery UI) and the script is executed when `#datepicker` is already in the DOM. With your code dates before `2015-12-01` can't be selected as required.

Comment: @VincenzoC How do I ensure the script is executed when #datepicker is already in the DOM?

Comment: Simply put your code **after** the `#datepicker` input in the HTML, or place `$("#datepicker").datepicker(...)` inside [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler (as you are probably already doing). Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue? Or maybe you can clarify further the problem you are having.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thank you, I was placing the minDate in the wrong spot, once I put inside the ready() it worked.