# How to set min and max date in the JQueryUI DatePicker in ASP.Net MVC 5 Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

Ok, so after following this [Date Picker Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1136464/Simplest-Way-to-Use-JQuery-Date-Picker-and-Date-Ti) I am able to create a datepicker. But I want to set some limit to the date picker. For example I only want the date picker to allow from 5th Jan 2017 to 5th Aug 2017". How can I achieve this. Note that I don't want to change the `dateFormat` property of the datepicker. Also, `dateformat` property is working properly.

Below is what I have till now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
            minDate: '05-Jan-17',
            maxDate: '05-Aug-17'
        });   

    });    
</script>
```

I selected minDate as '05-Jan-17' because I thought it should be put in the same format as I have set the `dateFormat` as `dd-M-yy`.

**Documentation of JQuery UI:**

[image]

After going through the [Documentation of JQUERY DatePicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) I thought I need to do something like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
         });
        $(".date-picker").datepicker("option", "minDate", "05-JAN-17");
    });
</script>
```

But this also does not work. Please help me.

**Model Class**

```
 public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime SongDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**
This also does not work.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date("05-Jan-2017"));
```

**EDIT 2**
Below change worked

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date("01-05-2017"));
        $(".date-picker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date("08-05-2017"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minDate` , `maxDate` should be `Date` object instead of string, so create a

`new Date(....)` in `minDate` and `maxDate` accordingly as per your requirement.

for reference, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847287/changing-mindate-option-in-jquery-datepicker-not-working)

Comment: Added the Edit. Can you check once.

Comment: oho, was there still any problem?

Comment: In Edit 1. I did not put the date in the right format. But Edit 2, worked.